# When the supremum of a real sequence is finite and not attained, it coincides with the limsup

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I'm having a bit of a problem with an exercise I have to make. In the exercise we are given the sequence $(s_n)$, which is a sequence of reals. Furthermore, we are given that $m=\sup\{s_n|n \geq 1\}<\infty$, and the supremum is not attained. We are to prove that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=m$.

Now if $s_n$ were an increasing sequence I would not have any trouble with believing this. But if $s_n$ for instance were decreasing, I don't see why this would be true. 
So say there is no lower bound, wouldn't that mean that even though there exists a supremum, that the $\limsup$ would be $-\infty$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The supremum $m$ is not attained hence, for every $N$, there exists $\epsilon_N>0$ such that $s_n\leqslant m-\epsilon_N$ for every $n\leqslant N$. Thus, $m=\sup\{s_n\mid n\geqslant N+1\}$ for every $N$, that is, $m=\limsup s_n$.

Comment: If it were decreasing then the sup would be attained, by the first element in the sequence.  The key is that if the sup is not one of the terms of the sequence then it must have terms arbitrarily close, and that says something about infinitely many terms.